# Long integers are being printed as negative values in C

Tags: c, numbers, long-integer

I wrote this algorithm to check if a number is prime and which numbers divide it. Now I want to know what are 600851475143 divisors (for example) and it outputs a negative number.
That's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* Discover what numbers divide the one read as input, then show if it's prime */

int main() {
    long checker;
    long step = 1;
    int divisors = 0;

    printf("Enter with the number you want know the divisors: ");
    scanf("%ld", &checker);
    while(step <= checker){
        /* check which numbers divide the number read*/
        if (checker % step == 0) {
            printf("%ld divides %ld\n", step, checker);
            step +=1;
            divisors +=1; 
            }
            else{
                step+=1;
                }
    }

    /*Now check if it is prime*/
    if (divisors == 2) {
        printf("ADDITIONAL INFO: %ld IS a prime number.\n", checker);
    }
    else {
         printf("ADDITIONAL INFO: %ld IS NOT a prime number.\n", checker);
    }
    printf("Done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Funny is that people didn't even read me before downvoting me. I'm already using long type variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you `scanf` to a `long` using the format string `%d` which expects the address of a `int` variable. The same goes for the way you use `printf`.

You need to replace every `%d` by `%ld` in your format strings.
You essentially need to do that because the size of an `int` and of a `long` are not equal.

Edit: GCC points out the mistake using the `-Wall` option.

Comment: Just had time to check it now, but I tried replacing all the `%d` formatters with `%ld` formatters, but program still prints negative value.

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa You must have forgotten some. I tested it.

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa Note that if you're using a 32 bits machine, your `600851475143` value is to big for a `long` (which would be 4 bytes long)

Comment: For the number I was working with only solution was using a `long long` type variable, `long` still printed negative value.
Now it works, thanks...